# using "them" or "it" as a pronoun for uncountable noun

Tags: pronouns

I'm an English learner. I have a question relating to using pronouns.  Here's my example sentence:

> Yesterday I bought some furniture for my kitchen. Some of **them is**
>   so expensive.

I don't know if I should use "them" or "it." And is "is" correct or not?

Comment: Hi KumaAra. I really didn't know that we have that community. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Hello, Huong. You've discovered a weird feature of English (there are many) – some mandatory non-count usages refer to etically countable assemblages. We can't say there were one, two, or seventy-seven furniture / cattle / police. We have to say there were three items of furniture, seventy-seven head of cattle, one police officer. With most nouns (five chairs, two dogs, three sailors ...), the count usage is thankfully available. // Here, you could use  '... I bought some furniture for my kitchen. Some of the pieces/items are so expensive.' Though '... Some of it is so expensive.' is better).

Comment: oh, thank you Edwin Ashworth. I've learned so much from your explaination.

Comment: It's very simple: "furniture" is a non-count noun so you can't use a plural pronoun as a pro-form; instead you have to use the pronoun "it". Now compare the count noun "knife" with non-count "furniture" _I bought some knives for my kitchen -- some of **them** were so expensive_ vs _I bought some furniture for my kitchen -- some of **it** was so expensive_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't use plural pronouns for mass nouns. *Furniture* is treated as a mass (or uncount or noncount) noun. See [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/furniture).

This might seem counter-intuitive since most people can count individual pieces of furniture.

Here's an example with another mass noun, *milk*:

Yesterday I bought some *milk* for the new refrigerator. Some of *it* is on the top shelf. I put the rest of *it* on the bottom shelf.

Comment: Yes we do, with notional agreement. But very rarely. 'The police were naturally called in to cover the conference. Some of them were there for hours.'

Answer (score 1):

As an English speaker the second sentence just doesn't make sense with "them" as constructed.

If some of the items you bought were very expensive then:

> *Yesterday I bought some furniture for my kitchen. Some of it was so expensive.*

changing the verb to *was* is a fair indication that you are referring to some of the items which you already have bought.

A lot of times a table and chairs are sold as a dinette set. So:

> *Yesterday I bought a dinette set for my kitchen. Some of them are so expensive.*

So *them* refers to dinette sets in general, not necessarily the one that you purchased.

To just refer to expensive pieces of kitchen furniture in general, then in the following sentence *it* is somewhat ambiguous. *It* can refer to kitchen furniture in general, or to some of the items you bought.

> *Yesterday I bought some furniture for my kitchen. Some of it is so expensive.*

Comment: thank you MaxW for your explaination. In short, i should use pronoun "It" to refer uncountable noun instead of "they" or "them", right?

Answer (score -2):

*Yesterday I bought some furniture for my kitchen. Some of them **are** so expensive.*

Don't use *it* or *is*, use *are* instead.

Comment: "Some of them" is wrong, though: it should be "Some of it".