# "the data that were observed." When to use plural verbs and pronouns with mass nouns?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

I was bumping into the word *them* used together with mass nouns in some translations from Chinese, but according to [this ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145195/using-them-or-it-as-a-pronoun-for-uncountable-noun), we don't use plurals with mass nouns.

And now I encounter [the 10k medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/probability-concepts-explained-maximum-likelihood-estimation-c7b4342fdbb1) which has the same behavior, and I am seriously concerned that I miss something.

> Maximum likelihood estimation is a method that determines values for the parameters of a model. The parameter values are found such that they maximize the likelihood that the process described by the model produced the data that **were** actually observed.

Perhaps the author wanted to say something like *data points that were observed*? Otherwise I don't understand where it is appropriate to use plural verbs and pronouns with mass/uncountable nouns and where not.

Comment: Sounds like you've understood it just fine. Some people still treat *data* as a plural, that's all.

Comment: Indeed, most of the academic world treats it as plural

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, it's a matter of style what you decide to use - a plural or singular form for a mass noun.