# What type of nouns are 'cattle', 'staff' and 'jeans'?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, pluralia-tantum

I was taught that there are four types of nouns:

- singular countable: journey, sheep, child
- plural countable: journeys, sheep, children
- singular uncountable: travel, water, fruit
- plural uncountable: groceries, customs,  thanks

Also

- Some words are only used with countable nouns: one, two, three, many, number, few
- Some words are only used with uncountable nouns: much, little, good/great deal, quantity, amount

Am I right?

What about the word 'cattle'? You can say neither 'three cattle' nor 'much cattle'. (According to Practical English Usage) What type of noun is it?

If it is an uncountable noun why I can say 'many cattle' but not 'much cattle'? Isn't 'many' used only with countable nouns and 'much' only with uncountable nouns?

Also, you might consider 'staff' or 'jeans'. You can say for example 'four staff' but not 'a staff'. (According to Practical English Usage)

Comment: Don't you believe what you read in _Practical English Usage_?

Comment: I believe what I read in Practical English Usage

Comment: 'Cattle' is a (1) arguably singular-form ('cattles' if it existed would be plural-form) (2) non-count (as you imply, you can't have 3 / 17 ...) cattle (3) plural-verb-mandating ('the cattle _are_ lowing') (4) etically countable (1 bull + 14 cows, say) noun. (1)-(3) are grammatical classifications, (4) a semantic one. //  'Staff' has already been covered on ELU. 'Jeans' is to the best of my knowledge always non-count (*5 jeans), obviously plural form, taking plural agreement, and etically countable (6 pairs of jeans). //// Note that so many nouns are used in both count and non-count contexts...

Comment: ...that it is almost always better to speak of count (2 coffees, 17 cakes) / non-count (I like coffee / cake) **usages**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stock \[uncountable\] vs livestock \[uncountable, plural\]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/527477/stock-uncountable-vs-livestock-uncountable-plural)

Comment: No, it doesn't. What do you mean by "etically countable"?

Comment: @Kyamond: I googled "etically countable" and got just **2** results - [this from ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145195/) 6 years ago, and [this from ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/527477/) 3 years ago (this *current* question hasn't been indexed by Google yet). You might find at least the second of those useful.

Comment: Jeans (and other nether garments) are like spectacles and scissors; a pair of them is one item. I would say they were a special category of 'plural countable' .

Comment: *Five cattle on the road* and *five jeans in the dryer* is the only way I know how to say those things. They are bog standard countable nouns in my dialect. https://www.bbc.com/news/av/uk-northern-ireland-36732010. https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Beautiful_Funeral_A_Novel_Maddox_Broth/1gZMDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22five%20jeans%22&pg=PA77&printsec=frontcover

Comment: I couldn't help thinking of the last verse of the Book of Jonah, which in the King James Bible reads _And should not I spare Nineveh, that great city, wherein are more than sixscore thousand persons that cannot discern between their right hand and their left hand; and also_ **much cattle?**_ More modern translations have 'many animals' or 'a lot of livestock'.

Comment: Can anyone tell if the division of nouns into 4 types is correct. And which one includes 'cattle', 'staff' and 'jeans'?

Comment: @Kyamond: You have to bear in mind that nobody "designed" English, nor is there any single authority able to lay down the law about how people use it. So if Phil is happy with *Five cattle on the road* and *five jeans in the dryer*, I'm certainly not going to argue - but I personally would only ever refer to *five **head of** cattle* and *five **pairs of** jeans*, and I wouldn't expect anyone to argue with *me* about my preferred usage!

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I think 'head' of cattle could be more a US preference. Brits are OK with e.g. _Three Cattle on Open Land_ by Henry Hadfield Cubley (1858–1934) (painting), _There were four reported incidents in 2018 and three in 2019, which resulted in the death of ten cattle_ (NHS bulletin about lead poisoning), _Five horses have also been injured and ten cattle have sustained glass cuts_ (BBC report about rubbish being dumped on farmland).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: *You* might be happy with *three cattle*, but I'm not! Plus I don't think it's always helpful to categorise *individual* preferences as reflecting US/UK usage splits. Personally, I doubt I've ever used ***cattle*** "naturally" in my life - any *specific* number of them (including ***one***) are always ***cows*** for me, and for a non-specific number, they're a ***herd** of cows*. But there are doubtless also many Americas who only ever refer to ***cows***, not ***cattle***.

Comment: (I never refer to ***steers*** or ***kine*** either! :)

Comment: ONG, FF you are killing me (laughter). Anyway, what you say is why this cattle issue should be dealt with by Australians and Americans/Canadians who have the wide-open expanses needed for cattle. I mean all those **cute British cows** grazing away happily in those green picture-postcard fields of Britain are not responsible for this situation. [ha ha]. But I agree, **three cattle** or any number just does not cut the mustard. FF, I think US cattle (and the Aussies) ranchers would object to not using the word cattle and sticking only to cows.

Comment: "Can anyone tell if the division of nouns into 4 types is correct. And which one includes 'cattle', 'staff' and 'jeans'?" You can class most **_usages_** into count/non-count // singular form/plural form (here, some odd nouns are difficult to classify) // taking singular or plural verb form (here again there are difficult cases ... both are sometimes available) //// referring to denumerable referents ('cattle' does; 'mercury' usually doesn't). This is a better schema for classification.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth All nouns have to be count OR non-count. There is no other classification.

Comment: @Lambie That's like saying 'all verbs must be transitive **_or_** intransitive. Some swing both ways. _Countification_ (the count usage of a noun once regarded as necessarily non-count) is well attested. As is massification. [Collins](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/grammar-pattern/variable-nouns) adopts the unsatisfactory 'solution' of adding a hybrid class, 'variable nouns', but there are so many of these (I'd say most nouns) it's impractical.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A particular noun in a particular context has to be one or the other. In context, they are not variable. They are one or the other. I'd like a coffee. I like coffee. One or the other, not both at the same time.

Comment: @Lambie " 'Coffee' is a non-count noun" (or " 'Coffee' is a non-count noun") is inaccurate. A particular noun used in a particular context is a _usage_ of that noun.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Say it however you want. **They can't be both count and non-count simultaneously**.

Answer (score 2):

There are countable nouns (journey, sheep, child), which have singular forms (given) and plural forms (journeys, sheep, children).

And there are uncountable nouns (travel, water, fruit) which don't have plural forms. Although these words may have plural forms in other, perhaps related, senses. You can talk about "waters" but it means something different to the non-count "water".

There are some countable nouns that are usually or always used in the plural. (jeans, groceries).  And there are some oddities (staff, cattle)

It is worth comparing "countable/uncountable" with the genders in other languages.  In French, every noun is "masculine" or "feminine". Sometimes you can tell by the meaning of a word which gender it is in, sometimes not. The masculine/feminine system is very mature. Even so there are still some oddities (*le/la diesel, le/la casse*) "Countable/uncountable" is a gender system that you are seeing being born. There are still lots of oddities.

There are lots of words that can be both countable and non countable, with a subtle difference in meaning (a beer/some beer).  There are countable plural words (like jeans) that refer to a countable-singular item, or (like groceries) that refer to a non-count item. There are words like "cattle" which began as a non-count word meaning "property" and then "live property" and then "cows" and so acquired a meaning that was plural, but it's grammar has not really caught up with its meaning.  Similarly "staff" is a word that has undergone lots of changes in meaning (stick/pole -> walking stick -> ceremonial walking stick carried by an army officer -> army officer -> army officer who isn't in direct command of troops -> Other people with similar office jobs in hospitals or offices -> the group of people working at a particular office.)  When words undergo such extreme changes in meaning, the grammar often doesn't keep up, and the word becomes an oddity.

So the categorisation of nouns into uncountable and countable is useful, but not complete or absolute, and you will have to deal with nouns that don't fit neatly into these categories.

Comment: Your closing sentence makes a strong point: some noun categories are on firmer ground than others are in English. So even though all nouns in English have a binary singular-vs-plural grammatical number for purposes of verb agreement, noun properties like countability are not necessarily locked down or binary. We always know the number of any noun but how to produce a noun phrase using noun to represent "the other" number can be unclear, forbidden, or variable between speech communities. *Sheep, children, deer, clothing* are all easy compared with *cattle, clothes, vermin, outskirts, gallows*.

Comment: This: "And there are uncountable nouns (travel, water, fruit) which don't have plural forms." is not true. The waters of the two rivers. My travels in the East. The fruits of our labour. I think bringing in other languages is just confusing. staff [not the stick] is staff(s), staff member(s) or member(s) of staff. For the stick, it just takes an s as a countable. All. the shepherds had staffs. I don't like that term oddity.

Comment: 'Jeans' is not a count noun; CGEL uses the useful test 'will a suitable numeral be acceptable?' You can't have three jeans. It's etically countable (you can certainly have three pairs of jeans, and count them), but countness is a syntactic not a semantic property. 'Cattle' is (unless it's recently been countified; see Wikipedia) always non-count, though cattle themselves can of course be counted. English has inconsistencies. Many nouns have both count and non-count usages (There are three chocolates left in the box; I like chocolate), and the term 'count noun' is often unhelpful.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Cattle is plural, so 10 cattle is OK but **most cattle ranchers** would use: 10 head of cattle.

Comment: @Lambie: *poultry* is plural, but *ten poultry* is not okay. Similarly, *police* is plural, but *ten police* is rather questionable. So your reasoning is incorrect (although lots of people will accept *ten cattle*).

Comment: @PeterShor I had already said I didn't like [number] plus cattle. But Time Magazine: **When *a hundred cattle* are feeding at a bunker, one can detect no more than an inch or so of variation in the height of their identical-looking rumps**.  I said I didn't like it and that I prefer 100 head of cattle. Can't you read what I wrote? I have zero idea what you mean about my reasoning. I was addressing James' comment re fruit, water and travel.

Comment: "And there are uncountable nouns (travel, water, fruit) which don't have plural forms." <---? *Gulliver's travels* / *Two coffees and three waters for table six, please* / *The fruits of my labours*. Those seem to have plural forms!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Those are bad examples. "Gulliver's travels" is a fixed phrase. "Two coffees and three waters for table six, please" You changed the meaning. You don't mean 'Spill the liquids on the table'. You mean "two cups of coffee and three glasses of waters".

Comment: But when you say "water" out of context, most people will think of liquid and not glass

Comment: @Kyamond There's no doubt that "water" and so forth are most often used uncountably. But it's definitely not the case that those nouns have no plural forms. QED. There's no arguing about that! ;)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You keep using this word "etically". I can't find any sources that say it means what you think it means. "[Etic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/etic)" is a word, and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/etically) says "etically" is the adverb form, but it has nothing to do with countability. The only hits for it on ELL or EL&U are your own words. Assuming it is a technical word in some field, could you reduce the level of your word choice so learners (and many native speakers) can understand?

Comment: 'Etically countable' means that the referent or defined assembly of referents of the noun involved are indeed discrete and that (given enough time and a numerate analyst etc) they could be counted. Thus '[17] mice' [in a cage, say], which is a count usage and etically (irrespective of the English grammar of countness) denumerable (17 in this example). But while 'furniture' is likewise etically countable, it is usually non-count. 4 tables + 13 chairs [in a showroom say] cannot be described as 17 furnitures. Likewise cutlery, jewellery.  // ...

Comment: 'Etic' means 'of or using language that avoids cultural (eg idiosyncratic grammar; illogical pairings [as with 'furniture' being usually non-count]) complications ... but corresponds well to the real world'. So if something can be counted, it's etically countable, whether the way it's described in say English uses a non-count usage or not. / I picked the word up many years ago in a [Wikipedia article]((https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun) on mass nouns / conflation of mass & collective nouns showing the count ~ denumerable mismatch in English. I'm not sure a better descriptor is available.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I grasped from context what you intend "etically countable" to mean. What's your source for this meaning? In what field is it used? Besides, if so few people understand it and we can't even look it up, maybe just use other words instead?

Comment: @gotube The last comment surely answers that. 'Etic' is in most dictionaries nowadays. // The snag is that if you don't use the specialist metalanguage available for such involved concepts, you're in danger of ending up with something like << furniture is countable but 'furniture' is uncountable >>. This is really a question belonging on ELU, though it is a duplicate there. Before it was moved here, I close-voted as a duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The word "etic" is in some dictionaries, but like I said above, ***it doesn't have any meaning to do with grammar***. Merriam-Webster, for instance has this: "*of, relating to, or involving analysis of cultural phenomena from the perspective of one who does not participate in the culture being studied*. There is no cultural analysis involved in determining that furniture can be counted even though it's uncountable.

Comment: Oxford Languages has 'relating to or denoting an approach to the study or description of a particular language or culture that is general, non-structural, and objective in its perspective.' Treating 'furniture, 'cutlery' as 'count' is counter-intuitive and a peculiarity of the particular language involved. As Wikipedia says, '_cutlery_ has _count_ equivalents in other languages'. It is an idiosyncrasy of English that 'cutlery' is perversely non-count. Ignoring such cultural trammels, it is inherently possible to count the pieces of a collection of spoons, knives etc. The cutlery is countable.

Answer (score 0):

cattle is countable, yes, and the meaning is plural.

AND: we say "head of cattle" (also used with sheep) so that gives us this kind of sentence:

**I have 20 head of cattle on my farm.** [*notice the singular*]

**I have **many head of cattle**** on my farm.    OR
**I have **a lot of** cattle on my ranch**.
**I have three cattle on my farm**. [not my personal preference]

Also from Wikipedia:

> Cattle can only be used in the plural and not in the singular: it is a
> *plurale tantum*.[31] Thus one may refer to "three cattle" or "some
> cattle", but not "one cattle". "One head of cattle" is a valid though
> periphrastic way to refer to one animal of indeterminate or unknown
> age and sex; *otherwise no universally used single-word singular form
> of cattle exists in modern English*, other than the sex- and
> age-specific terms such as cow, bull, steer and heifer.

Please note: Personally, I would not use a number with cattle as explained above.

[cattle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum)

staff: We say: **member of staff or staff members**. How many staff members are there in your office? For a walking stick, the word is countable. The shepherds have staffs.

Jeans: He was wearing **jeans**. How **many pairs [of jeans]** does he own?
Jeans is plurale tantum:

> A plurale tantum (Latin for 'plural only'; pl. pluralia tantum) is a
> noun that appears only in the plural form and does not have a singular
> variant for referring to a single object. In a less strict usage of
> the term, it can also refer to nouns whose singular form is rarely
> used.
>
> 'Putting on pants' is correct, 'putting on pant' sounds odd In
> English, pluralia tantum are often words that denote objects that
> occur or function as pairs or sets, such as spectacles, trousers,
> pants, scissors, clothes, or genitals. Other examples are for
> collections that, like alms and feces, cannot conceivably be singular.
> Other examples include suds, jeans, outskirts, odds, riches,
> surroundings, thanks, and heroics.

[plurale tantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum)

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle#:~:text=%22One%20head%20of%20cattle%22%20is,%2C%20bull%2C%20steer%20and%20heifer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle#:%7E:text=%22One%20head%20of%20cattle%22%20is,%2C%20bull%2C%20steer%20and%20heifer).

Many is for countable nouns only. Much is for non-countable nouns. BUT beware of this: We don't say: I have much coffee (usually). We use: I have a lot of coffee [in the cupboard]. a lot of is preferred to much in many declarative situations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't quite answer my question. When I give 4 types of nouns and ask which one "staff" belongs to, it doesn't make sense to answer "We say: member of staff or staff members". By the way, you don't need to use the word "member(s)":  "The staff are not very happy about the latest pay increase". Also, I realise that '"jeans" is "plurale tantum" but this still does not answer my question because it still can be countable or uncountable noun. Additionally, no one has clarified the confusion with the words "much" and "many".

Comment: @Kyamond Yes, staff is an uncountable noun. You can say member of staff, staff member or staff [everyone]. How does that not answer your question? Also, I did the best I could. You have asked **more than one question** here which is really not allowed.

Comment: And this: uncountable nouns: much, little, good/great deal, quantity, amount for example is not clear.

Comment: "You have asked more than one question here which is really not allowed." Oh, I'm sorry for that

Comment: And this: "uncountable nouns: much, little, good/great deal, quantity, amount" for example is not clear. No, jeans is ONLY uncountable. **I am wearing jeans.** **They all wore jeans.**  BUT **I own ten pairs of jeans**.

Comment: "uncountable nouns: much, little, good/great deal, quantity, amount for example is not clear." I mean that some words are only used with uncountable nouns. So you can say "I have much money" but not "I have much cats". You can say "a good deal of debt" but not "a good deal of pens"

Comment: No, we don't **usually** say: I have much money. I have little money, is used. We actually use "a lot of money" there or a great deal of, or a large amount of. However, **in the interrogative and negative we do use it**: Do you have much money? No, I don't have much money.

Comment: Also note that there is "Some words are only used with:" above "uncountable nouns: much, little, ..."

Comment: Okay so you can use negations and questions if you want. Still "Do you have much money" is better than "Do you have much cats".

Comment: I already **said**: Many is for countable nouns, much is for uncountable, obviously. Cats is countable.

Comment: That's right. And if you also agree that "cattle" is an uncountable noun then there is a problem. Why do we say "many cattle"? (Unless this is not your thesis then there is no contradiction. I think it is because you wrote "cattle in uncountable")

Comment: Not me, I wrote it is uncountable. Why do you **refuse** the ideas given such as head of cattle, pairs of jeans, members of staff. Many **head of cattle**// 5 head of cattle? "Cattle can only be used in the plural and not in the singular: it is a plurale tantum".

Comment: I don't refuse those ideas I'm simply trying to understand how words like 'cattle' or 'staff' work.

Comment: You wrote that 'cattle' is uncountable and 'many' is used with countable nouns. So why do we say 'many cattle'? Please don't write about plurale tantum. I understand the idea but I don't see the point in using it now.

Comment: @Kyamond The first LINE in my answer says: **cattle is uncountable, yes, but the meaning is plural**. See? Since the meaning is plural, it's like many people, many cattle, many sheep, many trout. However, many cattle might be pretty unusual.

Comment: So you actually don't agree that 'many' is used only with countable nouns? You say that 'many' is used only with plural (It does not matter whether the noun is countable or not)

Comment: @Kyamond WIKIPEDIA Cattle can only be used in the plural and not in the singular: it is a plurale tantum.[31] Thus one may refer to "three cattle" or "some cattle", but not "one cattle". "One head of cattle" is a valid. Many head of cattle were dying in the fields. [I meant countable]

Comment: Okay, okay. Could you agree or disagree with this: "You say that 'many' is used only with plural (It does not matter whether the noun is countable or not)"?

Comment: @Kyamond *Could you please stop now?* many is only for countable nouns. cattle means a group of animals, the meaning is plural.

Comment: I have no idea why you felt offended. You are saying things that contradict each other. You are saying 1) 'cattle' is uncountable 2) 'many' is only used with countable nouns 3) you can say 'many cattle'. When I point out this contradiction you are talking about plural and plurale tantum but this is irrelevant to the contradiction. Additionally, you said that 'cattle' is countable (in your main answer) and that 'cattle' is uncountable (in your comments) but I think this is simply a typo.

Comment: It is NOT a contradiction. Cattle is a group of animals. A group: cattle
Merriam Webster **plural noun**
cat·​tle ˈka-tᵊl 
Synonyms of cattle
1
: domesticated quadrupeds held as property or raised for use
specifically : bovine animals on a farm or ranch. //but we don't tend to say many cattle even though grammatically you can.

Comment: I think it IS a contradiction. If you look at all points 1), 2) and 3) they contradict each other. And it doesn't matter how many times you write "plural" and "plurale tantum" because it is irrelevant to the contradiction between points 1), 2) and 3)

Comment: Jeans is not countable or uncountable. I wear jeans and I have **five pairs of jeans**. We do not say: five jeans.